# Child element does not take full height of left element when its absolutely positioned - flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flex to make my 2 child columns same height. When i make 2nd child as position: absolute it does not take the full height. How do i solve this. below is how my html looks like

```
<section class="flex-box">
<section class="left-box">
big chunk of data
</section>
<section class="right-sec">
 right sec
<section>
</section>

.flex-box
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

.right-sec
    display block
    background-color  #EDF6F8
    width 100%
    position absolute
    left 100%
    -webkit-transition left 1s
    transition left 1s
    z-index 0

.right-sec.show
   display block
   z-index 1
   left 0px
```

Above code is for mobile. In this right-sec will be hidden in mobile on first load. When user clicks on a button show class will be added to it. So this section will overlap the left block. But issue is that right-sec does not take full height of left block as it is absolutely positioned i guess. Any fix so that right-sec takes same height as left-box?

Comment: Absolute positioned elements are taken out of flow, even in Flexbox, so it need a height, i.e. `height: 100%`.

Comment: Worked thanks. Earlier i tried adding on .right-sec which did not work. Now applied on .right-sec.show and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items